# Lat Lng to Makani Converter

Tags: google-maps, coordinates, coordinate-systems, coordinate-transformation

Is there anyone knows how to convert a latitude and longitude coordinate to a Makani Code?

Makani is the new addressing system being implemented in Dubai. I wonder how they convert coordinate points to 10 digit unique code called Makani.

see this [Makani Website](http://www.makani.ae/desktop/?lang=E)

Comment: I hope they will share their formula on this. This could really helps other existing apps and delivery-related sites/company to improve their service.

Comment: Currently, I think the only way is to use the Makani website or app and enter your location.

Comment: They also don't have API for that. I hope they could at least work on that so other developers can fit in with their new addressing system.

Comment: hi @lukaserat did u find any API for this?

Answer (score 1):

Just for your information, the Makani number IS based on a standard position system, the MGRS (Millitary Grid Reference System), so the conversion is straight forward enough, or so you would expect.

The problem is the implementation, you need to be accurate to 1m with the selected Co-Ordinates for where the guys at Makani decided to pick, or else your 'converted' Makani number WILL NOT be recognized by the system.

There are actually ways around this however; take for example....

Arabian Ranches, Al Mahra, Villa 124 (Street 4 Villa 12)

Makani Number: 26038 71480
MGRS Reference: 40R CN 26038 71480

Just drop onto Google Maps, select 'somewhere' on this Villa, and get the Co-ordinates...

Lat/Long: 25.049095, 55.275528

Convert this to Military Grid you get...

MGRS Reference: 40R CN 26036 71492

(Just to clarify CN is a 100Km Square Grid and the numbers are X,Y Meter References within that grid, so physically, my Lat/Lon Pick was actually only 2M West [26038-26036] and 12M North [71492-71480] of the Makani Guys Pick, unfortunately, the accuracy makes the error dramatic)

Goto Makani and enter 26036 71492, and you get a 'No Data Found' Error However; Makani DOES let you search by MGRS, so if you enter the complete '40R CN 26036 71492' into the Makani search, it shows the correct location, with the highlighted Makani Pin.

Hope this helps...